# Download the data of a picture Sentinel-5P

Tags: data, resolution, sentinel-5p

I am researching about air pollution in Tehran. While I want to export data about parameters like NO2, SO2 or HCHO in Sentinel-5P, in Google Earth Engine, the data that export in CSV are different from data has shown in charts in picture. The concentration of some parameters has numbers with four decimals. I need data with 0.0001 resolution.

How can I reach this resolution?

The data is in the picture and the corresponding CSV table.

[image]

[image]